# How to let resteasy create a class from a json property value that defines the type

Tags: java, json, jackson, jaxb, resteasy

The client sends a JSON with a property `type`. Possible values for `type` are `clipart` and `image` to a resteasy API.

On the API / server side resteasy should now automatically create an instance of the java `Clipart` class or an instance of the `Image` class. according to the `type` defined in the client JSON.

How I do that?

Comment: So basically you will have the `Clipart` and `Image` class prior right? All you need to do is check whats the incoming `type` based on which you want to create an instance of the respective prior class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution did it.

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = JSONImageItem.class, name = ItemType.TYPE_IMAGE),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = JSONClipartItem.class, name = ItemType.TYPE_CLIPART),
})
public abstract class JSONAbstractItem implements AbstractItem {
  JSONAbstractItem() {
    // for resteasy
  }
}

public interface AbstractItem {
  @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
  ItemType getType();
}

@JsonTypeName(ItemType.TYPE_IMAGE)
public class JSONImageItem extends JSONAbstractItem {
  JSONImageItem() {
  }
}

@JsonTypeName(ItemType.TYPE_CLIPART)
public class JSONClipartItem extends JSONAbstractItem {
  JSONClipartItem() {
    // for resteasy
  }
}

public enum ItemType {
  IMAGE, CLIPART;

  public static final String TYPE_IMAGE = "IMAGE";
  public static final String TYPE_CLIPART = "CLIPART";

  @JsonCreator
  public static ItemType fromString(String value) {
    return Arrays.stream(ItemType.values()).filter(v -> v.name().equalsIgnoreCase(value)).findFirst().orElse(null);
  }
}
```